# Клик по всем элементам кроме семи последних

Tags: python

Код кликает по всем `.lmc__block`, но как сделать так, чтоб клик производился по всем элементам, кроме последних семи элементов?

```
for country in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".lmc__block"):
    if country.is_displayed():
        country.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что мешает работать как со списками и сделать срез?

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".lmc__block")[:-7]
```

или если нужно только по отображенным отработать, то:

```
for country in [obj for obj in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".lmc__block") if obj.is_displayed()][:-7]:
    country.click()
```

P.S.

а разве `find_elements_by_css_selector` не считается устаревшей и вместо нее лучше использовать `find_elements`?

Answer (score 0):

```
res=[] #итоговый список
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".lmc__block"):
    if country.is_displayed():
        res.append(country) #наполняем список элементами

res=res[:-7] #укорачиваем список
for it in res:
    res.click()
```

Так или иначе получаем список со всеми элементами, затем производим манипуляции (укорачивание), и кликаем. Так же есть вариант с применением функции filter и генератором.